# How do I check if the word is in the list?

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I have an error, I am trying to check if word exists in the list, but I have got an error. The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rakhm/Desktop/untitled folder/code/python/voice-assistant/testing.py", line 24, in <module>
    if word in challenge:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType
```

The code:

```py
def check(word, list):
    if word in list:
        print("The word is in the list!")
    else:
        print("The word is not in the list!")


open = ["hello", "open", "give", "pls"]

challenge = "open"
ch1 = "open"
word = check(ch1, open)
if word in challenge:
    print('open')
```

Comment: return the string instead of printing it

Comment: Your function `check` does not return anything explicit. It's returning `None` by default, which is then set to the var `word`. That's why you get `NoneType` as the left operand (in `if word in challenge`).

Comment: Also, pick better names for your variables. Both [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) are built-in functions. If you use them as variable names you no longer have access to those functions.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly do not shadow built-in names. `list` and `open`are already defined in python.

The problem of your function is that it returns nothing so it is `None`. You might return `True` if it contains, `False` otherwise.

```py
def check(word, lst):
    if word in lst:
        print("The word is in the list!")
        return True
    else:
        print("The word is not in the list!")
        return False
```

If you use `something in other_string`, something must be string too. But your code `word` is None because your function returns nothing. It can be fixed like this:

```py
words = ["hello", "open", "give", "pls"]

ch1 = "open"
is_found = check(ch1, words) # it is True
if is_found:
    print(ch1, "is found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `print`, try `return` instead:

```
def check(word, list):
    if word in list:
        return "The word is in the list!"
    else:
        return "The word is not in the list!"


open = ["hello", "open", "give", "pls"]

challenge = "open"
ch1 = "open"
word = check(ch1, open)
if word in challenge:
    print('open')
```

Your code does 2 `print`s, so it will give a `None`:

```
>>> print(print())

None
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the purpose of extra **challenge** here?, You can simply return the word if exists in open list and by default it will return **None** from the def when not exists.

```
def check(word, open):
    if word in open:
        return word


open = ["hello", "open", "give", "pls"]
ch1 = "open"
word = check(ch1, open)
if word:
    print(word)
```